How to find out which Element the translated OBJ geometry belong to?
I have read Correlation of ids in obj files to the ids in the source model, but failed to find requested objectids in the OBJ file. None of the group ID resemble the expected objectids: 51, 52, 53, 54:
% grep "g Obj." svf2-translated.obj

g Obj.3285
g Obj.3285:1
g Obj.3287
g Obj.3287:1
g Obj.3286
g Obj.3286:1
g Obj.3288
g Obj.3288:1
g Obj.3288:2
g Obj.3287:2
g Obj.3286:2
g Obj.3285:2

How can we figure out, let's say, which Element Obj.3285 belongs to in the original design file?
The translation and the relevant part of object tree are as follows.
POST /modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "input": {
      "urn": "{{URL_SAFE_URN_OF_SOURCE_FILE}}"
  },
  "output": {
      "destination": {
          "region": "us"
      },
      "formats": [
          {
              "type": "obj",
              "advanced": {
                  "modelGuid":"{{GUID_VIEWABLE}}",
                  "objectIds" : [3313] 
              }
          }
      ]
  }
}



...
              {
                "objectid": 3313,
                "objects": [
                  {
                    "objectid": 51,
                    "name": "Basic Wall [364277]"
                  },
                  {
                    "objectid": 52,
                    "name": "Basic Wall [364425]"
                  },
                  {
                    "objectid": 53,
                    "name": "Basic Wall [364512]"
                  },
                  {
                    "objectid": 54,
                    "name": "Basic Wall [364593]"
                  }
                ],
                "name": "Exterior - Brick on CMU"
              }
...



